# ¿Cómo contar los registros de un dato especifico usando sentencias preparadas MySQLi (orientado a objetos)?

Tags: php, mysqli

Necesito contar todos los registros que tenga este identificador `pub-1374077Q`

Realice el siguiente procedimiento:

```
$id_pub = "pub-1374077Q";
$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT id FROM visitors_table where publishers=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$id_pub);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
    return $stmt->affected_rows;
} else {
    echo "0 registros";
}
```

pero no me ejecuta ningún error, no me muestra nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya se ha dicho, si lo que quieres es obtener el total de registros que cumplan con un determinado criterio, puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

```
$id_pub = "pub-1374077Q";
$total=0;
$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM visitors_table where publishers=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$id_pub);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($total);
$stmt-fetch();
```

Lo que se ha hecho ha sido lo siguiente:

- Declarar una variable `$total` inicializada a `0`, que será la que recogerá el valor traído de la consulta. Nótese que aquí no hay que preguntar si la consulta trajo filas o no. Cuando no traiga nada, `$total` se quedará valiendo `0`.
- Usar `COUNT` en la consulta para contar el total de registros que cumplen el criterio
- Después del `execute` usaremos `bind_result` para asignar el total de fila a la variable `$total`
- Luego usaremos simplemente `fetch`, dado que buscamos una sola fila/columna, `fetch` colocará el puntero sobre esa fila y `$total` adquirirá el valor que necesitamos. Con eso basta, no hay que abrir bucles `while` ni nada para leer los datos. Este procedimiento es explicado en el [Manual de PHP cuando dice](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php):

> Cuando se llama a `mysqli_stmt_fetch`() para obtener datos, el
>   protocolo cliente/servidor de MySQL coloca los datos de las columnas
>   vinculads en las variables especificadas por var1, ....

Comment: Gracias amigo, amigo disculpa como puedo cambiar la contraseña, darle la opción al usuario de poder cambiar su contraseña existe alguna respuesta sobre este tema :)

Comment: @Fernando el cambio de contraseña sería una consulta `UPDATE` como cualquier otra. Tendrías que capturar los datos del usuario y la nueva contraseña mediante un formulario por ejemplo y hacer la actualización. La mejor manera de hacerlo sería mediante Ajax. Hay varias respuestas sobre procedimientos parecidos, lo único que variará son los fines y el tipo de consulta, pero los principios serían los mismos.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a cambiar el procedimiento de la consulta, realizando un `SELECT COUNT` general.

Por lo tanto, su código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitors_table where publishers=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$id_pub);
$stmt->execute();
$data_null = null;
$stmt->bind_result($data_null); //Puede vincular varias columnas, pero no es necesario, estamos realizando un conteo de datos.
//if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "counted {$data_null} records\n";
}
//} else {}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Te saludo y te comento que deberías considerar migrar tus consultas a
>   la interfaz PDO, te dejo un ejemplo totalmente funcional y su
>   explicación

```
<?php

$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=social", "root", "pass");

$mail = 'mail@example.com';
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT COUNT(name) FROM profiles WHERE email = :mail");
$consulta->execute([":mail" => $mail]);
$procesa = $consulta->fetchColumn();

echo "Hay :".$procesa;
//Hay 3
```

1. Tengo una variable que en mi caso guarda un email que es el que voy a comparar para contar cuantos usuarios lo tienen y obtener un total
2. preparo la consulta pasando el marcador de nombre de este modo `:mail`
3. Cuando ejecuto la consulta paso en forma de array asociativo el marcador de nombre apuntando a la variable que contiene el email que va a consultar para contar, en este punto ya no es necesario indicar el tipo de dato que contiene la variable
4. La nueva variable `$procesa` accede a  `$consulta` y finalmente al método `fetchColumn()` **el cual es mucho mas conveniente puesto que como hará uso de una función de agregación y solo me va a devolver una columna no hace uso desmedido de memoria**
5. Puedo con un echo imprimir el valor directo de la query por que solo trae por dentro el conteo que se le solicito con la función de agregación

> 6. La ventaja de este método es que al procesar solo el resultado de la consulta, no necesitas iterar sobre la variable misma para obtener
>      el resultado, si no que directamente puedes imprimir el valor que
>      contiene la variable; que implica un proceso o tarea menos

Si quieres consultar a profundidad sobre fetchColumn, aquí la doc oficial

http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php