# Datos duplicado en php (mensaje de error)

Tags: mysqli, php7

tengo un formulario donde se ingresan los datos personales de una persona, en la tabla de la base de datos, puse como unique la cedula.
[image: tabla]

esta funcion me da un error en la consulta
[image: funcion]

y me arroja la consulta
[image: consulta]
pero lo que quiero es que le muestre al usuario un alert que le diga que existe ese registro y no ese mensaje, que obviamente no lo va a entender.

como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: En el insert tienes puesto `nombre_vot` pero en la tabla no tienes ningún campo con ese nombre, comprueba que se llamen todos igual, mirandolo bien no coincide casi ningun nombre con el de la tabla, eso es lo que te falla

Comment: perdon, ese es un print de otro error, pero sobre el que hablo si esta bien, ya subo otro print

Comment: Antes de hacer el `INSERT` puedes lanzar un `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM laTabla WHERE columnaUnica=elValo`, verificar si `total > 0` e imprimir el mensaje que desees.[Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/188176/29967), usando consultas preparadas además, que es lo recomendable.

Answer (score 0):

php tiene algunos métodos que te ayudan con eso como mysqli_error() y mysqli_errno(). a continuación te dejo un ejemplo:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bdcolmado") or die("unable to connect to db");
$result['succes']="false";
if(
    $connect->query("INSERT INTO producto (codigo, descripcion)
        VALUES (".$codigo.",'".$descripcion."')
    ")
){
    $connect->commit();
    $result['succes']="true";
}else{
    if(mysqli_errno($connect) == 1062){
        $result['error']="Se intentó insertar un dato duplicado: <br>
        código de error: ".mysqli_errno($connect)."<br>
        Mensaje de error: ".mysqli_error($connect)."
        ";
    }else{       
        $result['error']="".mysqli_errno($connect).": ".
        mysqli_error($connect)."";
    }
}
    echo json_encode($result);
```

Espero esto te funcione!